# Rails; Join multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activerecord

I'd love to join multiple tables and get the results.
Basically I'd love to create csv file based on transactions table.
However a transaction record

- might have has_one relation with either invoice or refund. (`transaction 0..1 <=> refund/invoice 1`)
- the invoice always has relation with an account.

What is the best solution to fetch the all records to render csv of these records?

I'd love to hear some advice.

Ex.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invoice
  has_one :refund
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transactions
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :refunds
end

class Refund < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :transactions
end


class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What might be the problem with your current solution? This forum is not so others would think in your place, but instead to help you solve issues or help with some problems.. :)

Comment: Yup totally agree. Give it a whirl yourself. Break things... show us the broken pieces and then we can help you put them back together again :)

Comment: Basically your schema looks OK, but many things depends on how you decide to refine your idea with the code, code than you haven't yet wrote (e.g. in your model). My advice to you is to try to do query in console (with joins, includes ...) and verify if your schema and associations are really suitable to obtain your target.